# The requested service ' has not been registered in Quartz.net using autofac

Tags: c#, .net, autofac, quartz.net

I am using autofac to register Quartz but I am running into a problem I get this:

```
The requested service 'AuthMatcher.ConsumerSchechuler.ConsumerSchechulerJob' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
```

when the NewJob method gets invoken inside the jobFactory :IjobFactory class.

the FactoryClass:

```
    using Autofac;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Spi;
using System;

namespace AuthMatcher.ConsumerSchechuler
{
    public class ConsumerJobFactory : IJobFactory
    {
        private IScheduler _scheduler;
        private readonly IContainer _container;
        public ConsumerJobFactory(IContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
        {
            //test to see what happenes, it returns null
            var service =  _container.ResolveOptional<ConsumerSchechulerJob>();
          // this is where the exception happens
            return (IJob)_container.Resolve(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
        }

        public void ReturnJob(IJob job) { }
    }
}
```

the Autofac startup class:

```
namespace Workers
{
    public class InstallerClass
    {
        private static readonly ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public static IContainer Startup()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<Application>().As<IApplication>();
            builder.RegisterType<RabbitMQImpl>().As<IQueue>().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<ConsumeSchechuler>().As<IConsumeSchechuler>();
            builder.RegisterType<BotFactory>().As<IBotFactory>();
            var instance = QuartzInstance.Instance;
            builder.RegisterType<ConsumerSchechulerJob>().As<IJob>();
            builder.RegisterInstance(QuartzInstance.Instance).As<IScheduler>();

            return builder.Build();

        }
    }
```

}

main class which is calling the install and also instantiating the JobFactory
I am passing the container which I get from the startup class with all the dependencies to ConsumerJobFactory.

```
namespace Workers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var container = InstallerClass.Startup();
            using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {

                var app = scope.Resolve<IApplication>();
                var _scheduler = container.Resolve<IScheduler>();
                _scheduler.JobFactory = new ConsumerJobFactory(container);
                app.Run();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated been stuck on this for too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The requested service `AuthMatcher.ConsumerSchechuler.ConsumerSchechulerJob` has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

This error message indicates that `ConsumerSchechulerJob` has not been registered. If you look at your registration

```
 builder.RegisterType<ConsumerSchechulerJob>().As<IJob>();
```

You register `ConsumerSchechulerJob` as `IJob` but not as `ConsumerSchechulerJob` so Autofac doesn't have any registration for `ConsumerSchechulerJob`. To fix this you should register it.

```
 builder.RegisterType<ConsumerSchechulerJob>()
        .As<IJob>()
        .As<ConsumerSchechulerJob>();
```

or

```
 builder.RegisterType<ConsumerSchechulerJob>()
        .As<IJob>()
        .AsSelf();
```